# Iterate over registry keys

Tags: jscript, wsh, registrykey

I already know how to read registry values using [RegRead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x05fawxd(v=vs.84).aspx):

```js
var WshShell = W.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
var val = WshShell.RegRead("HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Audio\\EnableCaptureMonitor");
WScript.Echo(val);
```

Now I want to iterate over all keys in some registry path. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of a couple ways. The first (and easiest, IMO) is to use the `reg.exe` command-line utility (available since Windows XP) to do the dirty work for you. Here's an example that queries all subkeys of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software`:

```js
var objShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var objExec = objShell.Exec("REG QUERY HKLM\\SOFTWARE");
var strKeys = objExec.StdOut.ReadAll();
var a = strKeys.split("\n");

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    WScript.Echo(a[i]);
}
```

Note that the utility seems to return an extra newline at the start and end of the output, so be prepared to filter a couple of blank entries in your array.

The second method uses WMI's `StdRegProv` class. It's a bit of a pain to use from JScript (vs VBScript) but it's possible. Here's an example showing how to iterate the same subkeys:

```js
// Constant for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE...
var HKLM = 0x80000002;

// Get an instance of the StdRegProv class...
var objService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\\\.\\root\\default");
var objReg = objService.Get("StdRegProv");

// Prepare the EnumKey method...
var objMethod = objReg.Methods_.Item("EnumKey"); 
var objParamsIn = objMethod.InParameters.SpawnInstance_(); 
objParamsIn.hDefKey = HKLM; 
objParamsIn.sSubKeyName = "Software"; 

// Execute the method and collect the output...
var objParamsOut = objReg.ExecMethod_(objMethod.Name, objParamsIn); 

// If successful, iterate the subkeys...
if (objParamsOut.ReturnValue === 0) {
    if (objParamsOut.sNames != null) {
        var a = objParamsOut.sNames.toArray();
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
            WScript.Echo(a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```